# Update Data in the list which has same item using RxJava

Tags: operators, rx-java

I have a list of class called contacts which has three property like below.

```
public class Customer {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int amount;


    public Customer() {

    }
}
```

List customers = new ArrayList();

If I add any customer object to the list which has same id and name, then it should not add a new object into the list. Amount should get added to the existing item if it has any object.

For Eg

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(1,"Raja",10);
Customer c2 = new Customer(1,"Raja",15);
Customer c3 = new Customer(2,"Raja",10);
```

if I add the above three to the list. Then the c1 and c2 get merged into single one into the list with amount 25.

How can I achieved it through RxJava operator.

Comment: What you want is your specific data store of Objects/Customers, what it's has to do specifically with RxJava? RxJava is for event based programming, and you're looking for is for collections

Comment: We have so many operators in RxJava like groupby, join and filter. Can we achieve it through any of the operators.

Comment: No, and you shouldn't use Rx for this purpose - you're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.